# What is the distribution of the predictions in linear regression?

Tags: regression, probability, normal-distribution

As the question states, what is the distribution of the predicted $y$ values in linear regression? I'm sure this question has been answered somewhere before but I can't seem to find it for some reason. 
 
Edit: forgot to mention that I'm making standard homoskedastic normal residual assumptions.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Do you mean the conditional distribution or the pooled (marginal) distribution of all predictions combined together? Also, you’ve tagged this with [tag:normal-distribution]. Why? The normal distribution could come up in this discussion but does not have to.

Comment: Edited post - forgot to mention assumptions. I'm looking for the conditional distribution given $X$, if that's what you mean.

Comment: By linear regression, do you mean a maximum likelihood model where you assume that the conditional distribution of $y$ given $X$ is Normal?

Comment: @Firebug, maximum likelihood is a type of estimator, not a model.

Comment: @RichardHardy by 'maximum likelihood model' I refer to models that are estimated using maximum likelihood. This is quite commonplace as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @Firebug, this sounds fine like a shorthand to be used by experts that know the context, but taken literally it can be confusing for beginners – that's all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume a traditional linear regression and that the data follow the model, i.e, given $X$ the corresponding value $Y|X$ will be distributed as $\mathcal{N}(X \beta, \sigma^2)$ for some *true* values of $\beta$ and $\sigma$. In this case,  the least squares estimator (and the MLE) for $\beta$, $\hat{\beta} = (X^\top X)^{-} X^\top Y$ is just a linear transformation of multivariate normal random variables $Y$ and thus has the distribution $\mathcal{N}(\beta, (X^\top X)^{-} \sigma^2)$. ([See this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/285992/69595))

Then the prediction for a new $X_j$ is given by $\hat Y_{j} = X_j (X^\top X)^{-} X^\top Y $ which again is a linear transformation of a multivariate normal so

$$\hat Y_{j}| X_j \sim  \mathcal{N}(X_j\beta, X_j(X^\top X)^{-} X_j^\top \sigma^2)$$

This neglects any uncertainty about the predictors $X$ and $X_j$ and what values they will have and treats them as deterministic quantities. If you assume some distribution for $X$ and $X_j$ then the distribution of $\hat{\beta}$ and thus $\hat Y_{j} | X_j$ will also change.

Comment: While correct, this perspective does not seem to be practically relevant. In regression applications, we do not have the true values $\beta$ but only the estimates $\hat\beta$. That makes the distribution of the predictions much more involved. Stephan Kolassa's answer goes in that direction.

Comment: In my context I do have the true values $\beta$ so this was the answer I was looking for.

Comment: @mrepicfoulgermrepic1123, if you know $\beta$ and use $X_j \beta$ instead of $X_j \hat{\beta}$, then the predictions are just deterministic and not normally distributed.

Answer (score 6):

The precise answer will depend on whether your errors are normally distributed (and homoskedastic, and independent). If so, future observations follow a t distribution, see section 3.5 in [Faraway (2002)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf), "prediction of a future value", although [I would have called the intervals "prediction intervals" rather than "confidence intervals"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info).

If your errors are non-normal, you can often assume a t or normal distribution by arguing asymptotics, but I don't have a reference at hand.

Comment: The *predictions* are t-distributed?

Comment: Edited post - forgot to mention assumptions.

Comment: This does not give t-distributed predictions: `set.seed(2023); N <- 1000; x <- rbinom(N, 1, 0.5); y <- 7*x + rnorm(N); plot(density(y))`. The predictions are bimodal. I think you are addressing a different question.

Comment: As I read the question it is just about the sampling distribution of $\hat{Y}_j$ in relation to the true parameters. The more relevant/interesting deviation $Y_j - \hat{Y}_j$ follows a t-distribution when assuming homoskedastic residuals with linear regression, so in this sense one could say the predictions follow a t-distribution centered on the hypothetical "actual" value of $Y_j$ (which is a random variable).

Comment: @Dave: prediction intervals in standard linear regression, as asked in the question, usually assume a t distribution, *conditional on predictors*, which I assumed was intended. I don't quite understand what your example should be telling us, to be honest. Yes, *unconditional* predictions may be bimodal. But how often are we interested in unconditional predictions - especially if we don't know anything about the distribution of the predictors?

Comment: Reading this answer and taking it literally, I share Dave's confusion. At the same time I also understand Stephan's explanation in the comment. For clarity, why not make the conditioning explicit in the answer?

Comment: The distribution of estimates and predictions is Gaussian. But for the computation of confidence intervals or prediction intervals we use a t-distribution. The question asks for the former.